# Conflict between Google Drive shortcuts and Safari keyboard shortcuts

Tags: macos, keyboard, google-apps

I am working with Google Drive (Google Document) and I have the next shortcut predefined to switch between windows in the same app: ⌘ + Shift + <

The thing is that if I use that shortcut while I am working in a Google Document it doesn't work because it is assigned to another function in Google Drive.

Is there a way I can solve this conflict?

Comment: Usually the shortcut for swapping windows is ⌘ + \` (the ~ key without shift)

Comment: If you question is about changing the google drive shortcut `cmd + shift + <` that extends selection to the right,  you can't. The google drive app doesn't allow user to change the shortcuts. You can ask for details in https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/drive

Comment: @Daniel I change it to a custom one because it is easy for me than ⌘ + `